# Is there a way to check if wireless network allows ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, ports

I am at the public library currently using a mac book and I am trying to SSH into my server. I am normally able to do so in other places that are not on my local network, but I am not able to here. Without asking the library staff if they have it open (because they have no idea) is there a way to check if it is open?

the following is the command I am running that is not working:

ssh mywebsite.com -p 2222

Comment: Simple as it may seem: If it doesn’t work, it isn’t open.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the answer. It seems odd that there isn't some way to check what ports are open with a definitive answer that can rule out typos or "my" bad coding.

Comment: Why would there be a way? In `iptables` terms, if the firewall is set to `DROP` a packet, the sender never knows. The connection or whatever process will time out, that’s all.

Comment: @Daniel for reasons such as the one I experienced. If there was a known mac terminal input than I'd know it wasn't the site or my typing but the network I'm on... This would allow for easy checks to eliminate where the problem could be...

Answer (score 0):

You can try running a nmap on port 22 (ssh), although they may have this blocked

```
nmap -p 22 myurl.com
```

while the port 22 is the default, you could change it to an alternate port (perhaps 80), which would be less likely to be blocked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check when I'm at the library again and update on whether this is an acceptable answer.

Comment: And I'd probably want to use 443 :)